# how do i fix "tempt to index nil with 'character'"

Tags: lua, roblox

here is a script

```
local teleportParts = {
    game.Workspace.Part1,
    game.Workspace.Part2,
    game.Workspace.Part3,
}

local function teleportPlayer()
    local randomIndex = math.random(1, #teleportParts)
    local randomPart = teleportParts[randomIndex]
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = randomPart.CFrame
end

local part = game.Workspace.PartToTouch
part.Touched:Connect(teleportPlayer)
```

this script need to teleport player to parts from the list

Comment: I assume `LocalPlayer` is only client sided, where does your script run?

Comment: in teleport part

Comment: I meant "where" as in "client or server". I have no knowledge in Roblox but one reason for the LocalPlayer to not exist is when there is no local player. E.g. on a server.